# Is there a way to solve the iOS 14 Widget flicker issue?

Tags: ios, swiftui, flicker, ios14, widgetkit

I'm experiencing a strange graphic issue (flickering) for iOS 14 widgets on the Home Screen and also in the Widget Gallery. The problem seems to occur after an app update gets installed. During development I thought this is a problem with the iOS Simulator, but now users reporting this issue, after I released an app update.

Was someone experiencing the same problems? Is there a fix for it or is it a bug from Apple?

Here are 2 videos showing the problem. Once on the Home Screen and once in the Widget Gallery. [Home Screen flickering](https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/de-de/#B105oqs3qIDG9bh;299D65E3-D46D-478F-8EB6-295DDE46F631)
[Widget Gallery flickering](https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/de-de/#B105oqs3qIDG9bh;0F283C69-2E34-4FAB-8EED-533ED52E09AF)

Answer (score 0):

I’m having the same issue. “Color Widgets” flickers and it’s irritating at times.

This is an issue with iOS 14.0. (This issue was there in the betas, not sure why apple didn’t fix it)

I guess Apple will get it fixed it in the next iOS update since a lot of users are complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Seems iOS 14 issue but while development you can avoid this by removing Widget from home screen before adding new version in simulator/device.